# SQL Server Change Data Capture - how to separate log entries by transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, transactions, change-data-capture

I'm just getting started with SQL Server's Change Data Capture functionality. I'd like to be able to pick out entries from the change table based on which transactions they were part of. Is there a way to do this? The transaction ID field in those tables doesn't seem to correspond to anything meaningful.

I realize that there are the LSN's and you can look for general start and end times, but is it possible to account for multiple transactions which run at the same time, each affecting different records? (with potentially interleaving start and end times for different operations)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem a few minutes ago.  I did some Googling and it appears there's a [`cdc.lsn_time_mapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510494.aspx) table that may do this for you.

Here's how I used it (not sure how reliable this is, what would happen if you truncate the transaction log, etc.):

```
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('Application_Person');
SET @to_lsn   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn();
SELECT m.*, c.*
FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_Application_Person(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all') c
INNER JOIN cdc.lsn_time_mapping m ON c.__$start_lsn = m.start_lsn
```

Other useful links for future readers:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510494.aspx (How to set up
  CDC)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627.aspx (How to
  query changes)